# MySQL: Joining to Subquery on YEAR(date)

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a table that summarizes data from another one.  The summary is to be by year that is extracted from a date field.  When I try to include a new field to the table with a subquery, I get a 1054 (unknown column) error in the ON clause.  I have tried joining on `date` and get the same error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS park_factor (
SELECT YEAR(games.date) AS year
    , games.home_team
    , sum(games.runs0) AS ht_runs
    , sum(games.runs1) as away_runs
    , round(leagues.rules_schedule_games_per_team/2,0) AS home_games
    , x.home_losses
FROM games 
    INNER JOIN leagues ON games.league_id=leagues.league_id
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT YEAR(games.date) as year
          , games.home_team
          , COUNT(*) as home_losses
      FROM games
      WHERE games.runs1>runs0
      GROUP BY year, games.home_team
      ) AS x ON x.year=games.year AND x.home_team=games.home_team
GROUP BY year, games.home_team, home_games, home_losses );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `games.year` column, which is what is causing your error. You need to `JOIN` using

```
 x.year = YEAR(games.date) AND x.home_team=games.home_team
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while @Nick was answering.  The code that works is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS park_factor (
SELECT YEAR(games.date) AS `year`
    , games.home_team
    , sum(games.runs0) AS ht_runs
    , sum(games.runs1) as away_runs
    , round(leagues.rules_schedule_games_per_team/2,0) AS home_games
    , x.home_losses
FROM games 
    INNER JOIN leagues ON games.league_id=leagues.league_id
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT YEAR(games.date) as `year`
          , games.home_team
          , COUNT(*) as home_losses
      FROM games
      WHERE games.runs1>runs0
      GROUP BY year, games.home_team
      ) AS x ON x.`year`=YEAR(games.date) AND x.home_team=games.home_team
GROUP BY YEAR(games.date), games.home_team, home_games, home_losses );
```